# ¿Como generar un elemento en una ubicación aleatoria de una matriz? c# consola

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random elemento = new Random();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cual seria la matriz en el codigo que has publicado ?

Answer (score 1):

podria ser algo como

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] numeros = new int[10,10];

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un valor");
        int valor = Convert.ToInt32()Console.ReadLine());

        Random elemento = new Random();

        int X = elemento.Next(0, 10);
        int Y = elemento.Next(0, 10);

        numeros[X][Y] = valor;

    }
}
```

[Matrices (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)